# No content provider for setVideoUri?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I have several VideoViews inside of a RecyclerView. I want to load videos from my web server into these views.

I am getting the following error:

> W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://giftube.kjdion.com/mp4/3.mp4: 
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: 
>   http://giftube.kjdion.com/mp4/3.mp4

If I click the VideoView, the app also crashes instantly.

You can clearly see if you visit http://giftube.kjdion.com/mp4/3.mp4 that it works.

I added INTERNET permission to my manifest.

Here is my code for the adapter view holder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Scrape scrape = list.get(position);

    holder.textTitle.setText(scrape.getTitle());
    holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Global.url+"/mp4/"+scrape.getId()+".mp4"));
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textTitle;
    public VideoView videoView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        videoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_video);
    }
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Can you show the media player code, please

Comment: There is no media player code. I've also tried using `setMediaController(new MediaController(context))` which fixed nothing.

Comment: `If I click the VideoView, the app also crashes instantly.` where is the click action?

Comment: There is no click action at all yet. Also, the VideoView is a simple xml declaration with a width and height, using id `main_video`.

Comment: You can use it like below to play the video:

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://abhiandroid-8fb4.kxcdn.com/ui/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/videoviewtestingvideo.mp4");
simpleVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);